# Why is my image not showing up when using html and flask?

Tags: python, html, css, image, flask

I have the image in the static folder but the image is not displaying however the css part is working fine. How do I make it so that my image is displayed. I have tried using normal html and inserted the url_for function from flask but it doesn't want to appear.

```css
body {color:#3366CC;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE = edge">
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device - width, initial-scale = 1.0">
        
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{url_for('static', filename='Styles/index.css')}}">
        
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="logo">
                <image scr="{{url_for('static', filename='Images/logo.png')}}", alt="lol">
            </div>
        </header>
        
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Change `<image scr=` to `<image src=`

Answer (score -1):

You use `scr` attribute instead `src` (so it's just a wrong typing).